# How can we get the Suspension time of an account using Admin Directory API

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to get the reports for all the Suspended accounts with a field "SuspensionTime" like the "creationTime". I'm unable to fetch the "SuspensionTime" of an account though the API.

I'm using the following Documentation referred by the Google.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/guides/manage-audit-admin

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list) method from the Reports API. The thing with this is that it requires the userKey parameter, which means that you depend on knowing which admin performed the action. It is easier if you have only a couple of admin accounts doing user suspensions.

You would need to send "SUSPEND_USER" in the event name field, and "admin" in the applicationName field to get all the user suspensions performed by that admin, and you will get the date and time in the "time" file of the response.

Comment: You can use "all" as the userKey

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the Activities API: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list?apix_params=%7B%22userKey%22%3A%22all%22%2C%22applicationName%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%22eventName%22%3A%22SUSPEND_USER%22%7D

If the suspension comes from Google you can inspect the Users Usage Reports: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/user/accounts

The field disabled_reason usually contains the date of the suspension.